# Extjs4 gridpanel row data not same with json data store

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

i'm new with extjs4, i have a problem with gridpanel that should be show number of rows from data store. My problem is data store retrieve json with 6 rows but why in grid panel only shows 4 rows...

here's the grid

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id: 'gridcb',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('mystore'),
        columns: [
            {header: 'ci',  dataIndex: 'co'},
            {header: 'co', dataIndex: 'co', flex:1},
            {header: 'durasi', dataIndex: 'durasi'},
            {header: 'issue', dataIndex: 'id'}
        ],
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
    });
```

here's the store

```
var mystore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

        storeId:'mystore',
        fields:['ci', 'co', 'durasi', 'id'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'exe_report_issue_order.php?function=store',
            actionMethods : 'POST',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'rows'
            }
        }
    });
```

and json return 6 rows that unique. why only show 4 rows...

```
{success:true,
rows:[{ "ci":"2012-04-17 17:13:48",
        "co":"2012-04-17 17:13:59",
        "durasi":"00:00:11",
        "id":"154"
        },
        {"ci":"2012-04-26 08:05:00",
         "co":"2012-04-26 10:00:00",
         "durasi":"01:55:00",
         "id":"157"
        },
        {"ci":"2012-04-26 13:00:00",
         "co":"2012-04-26 17:00:00",
         "durasi":"04:00:00",
         "id":"158"
        },
        {"ci":"2012-04-17 13:00:00",
         "co":"2012-04-17 17:00:00",
         "durasi":"04:00:00",
         "id":"65"
        },
        {"ci":"2012-04-18 08:00:00",
         "co":"2012-04-18 10:00:00",
         "durasi":"02:00:00",
         "id":"65"
        },
        {"ci":"2012-04-18 17:45:00",
          "co":"2012-04-18 22:00:00",
          "durasi":"04:15:00",
          "id":"65"
        },
        {"ci":"2012-04-18 23:30:00",
         "co":"2012-04-19 03:30:00",
         "durasi":"-20:00:00",
         "id":"65"
        }
    ]
```

}

is anybody can explain to me???please.
thanks

Comment: can you also include the json that is being returned?

Comment: i'm not sure..but when the 'id' are same it render the last one..even when i didnt include the 'id' fields no changes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have items with a duplicate id in your store, they must be unique.

Comment: if found it...actually the 'id' is not identifier for each row (like primary key)..it's just a column with name 'id'...i solved it just by renaming the column..

Comment: New version of ExtJs has `idProperty` definition in the model - by default it's `id`, that's why these records were treated as duplicates.